# What is $|k|_3$?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I'm reading the 2003 *Recurrence Sequences* and trying to figure out notation related to S-units. It does not  appear earlier in the section (or the book, as far as I can tell) and doesn't appear in the "Notation" section. Full context:

Let $S$ denote the set $S=\{2,3\}$ and write, for any integer $k$,
$$|k|_S=|k||k|_2|k|_3$$
for the *$S$-norm* of $k$. Notice that the $S$-norm of an integer is 1 if and only if the integer comprises powers of 2 and 3 only in its prime factorization: Such an integer is called an *&S$-unit.*

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html